# Plot two time series: axis issue

Tags: r, plot, time-series, zoo

I am trying to plot two time series on the same x-axis (but different y-axis).  However I am having issues with the y-axis labels overlapping.

The code to generate the issue is below.

```r
set.seed(123)
library(zoo) 
plot(as.zoo(cbind(rnorm(1000,.1,50),runif(1000,0,100))))
```

You should see the lowest y-tick value for the first plot overlaps with the top y-tick value on the second plot.  How would you go about fixing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `las=1`, `cex.axis=.7` and some `ylim` modification? See `?par` for a detailed explanation of what `las` and `cex.axis` do

```
set.seed(123)
library(zoo) 
plot(as.zoo(cbind(rnorm(1000,.1,50),runif(1000,0,100))), 
 cex.axis=.7, las=1, ylim=list(c(-160,160), c(0,100)))
```

which produces:

[image]

Another solution would be using `yax.flip=1`

```
set.seed(123)
library(zoo) 
plot(as.zoo(cbind(rnorm(1000,.1,50),runif(1000,0,100))),  yax.flip=1)
```

[image]